# Latest From NSArray

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsdate

I have NSdate object in NSArray. I want to get latest from the array of dates.

```
NSDate *tomorrow = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:(24*60*60) sinceDate:[NSDate date]];

    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

    NSDate *yesterday = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:-(24*60*60) sinceDate:[NSDate date]];


    NSMutableArray* arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:today,yesterday,tomorrow,today,yesterday,tomorrow, nil];
```

My return value should be tomorrow(latest date).

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
[arr lastObject]; //Returns the object in the array with the highest index value.
```

or

```
[arr objectAtIndex:[arr count]-1];
```

Comment: Actually I need max date not latest added date to the array

Comment: In this case you need to sort array and then take the last object

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sortedArrayUsingComparator](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) and [compare](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for this From NSArray & NSDate Class respectively

```
NSArray *sortedDates = [arr sortedArrayUsingComparator: 
                                                     ^(id obj1, id obj2) {
                                                          return [obj1 compare:obj2];
                                                     }];
NSLog(@"%@",[sortedDates lastObject]); // SortedDates Contains dates in ascending Order (last object of the array returns the latest date.
```

Comment: Or `NSArray *sortedDates = [arr sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];`.

Comment: @MartinR : Initially I Thought It will not work for NSDate. but it is working like charm :)